# Encrypt String in winrt c# and decrypt it in c# .net

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

How one would encrypt a string using asymmetric encryption on WinRT Metro in C# and decrypt this in classic Windows, let's say in a webservice?

I want to use RsaPkcs1 algorithm and I can see that `CryptographicKey` class and `RSAParameters` class are not even near compatible.

How this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution on how to export the keys from the `CryptographicKey` in a format that .net 4 can successfully use.
`CryptographicKey` has 2 functions 1. `Export`  and 2. `ExportPublicKey`. I used the 1st function that exports the private key. This function has 2 parameters 1st is the type of export and 2nd the byte[] that will fill. 
If `CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Capi1PrivateKey` is used, the blob that `Export` will produce is compatible with the WinCAPI that `RSACryptoServiceProvider` of .net 4 can import.

#### WinRT

```
String str = "String To Encrypt";
IBuffer buf = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(str,BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE);
String AsymmetricAlgName = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1;
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider asym = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgName);
CryptographicKey key = asym.CreateKeyPair(512);
IBuffer enc = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buf, null);
byte[] encryptedbyteArr;
CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(enc, out encryptedbyteArr);
String encryptedBase64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedbyteArr);


//Export the private Key in WinCapi format

byte[] privatekeyBytes;
CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(key.Export(CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Capi1PrivateKey), out privatekeyBytes);
String privatekeyBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(privatekeyBytes);
```

`encryptedBase64Str` now contains the encrypted string in Base64. And lets say that `encryptedBase64Str="BwIAAACkAABSU0EyAAIAAAEAAQCFrMTqMU3T14zSUM5..."`

#### Web Service

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
String privateKey64 = "BwIAAACkAABSU0EyAAIAAAEAAQCFrMTqMU3T14zSUM5...";
String EncryptedString = "PbauDOjqMLD2P6WSmEw==";
byte[] EncryptedDataBlob = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedString);
byte[] privateKeyBlob = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey64);
byte[] decryptedBytes;
rsa.ImportCspBlob(privateKeyBlob);
decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(EncryptedDataBlob, false);
String decryptedString =System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(decryptedBytes);
```

`decryptedString` now contains the decrypted string that WinRT had.

Comment: By the way, I am not saying that exporting the key in that way is secure, but it shows how to export-import keys between winrt and .net

Answer (score 0):

You must use public key to decript the content.
Don't forget export public key in WinRt Version!